# forKeyPath troubles with Quartz Composer and MacRuby

Tags: cocoa, key, macruby, quartz-composer

I am having some issues with setting values using MacRuby and Cocoa. I have the inserted the QCView and the QCPatchController into the XIB and loaded the composition into the QCPatchController. Everything is running but I cannot access the published inputs on the QCView.

```
attr_accessor :myQCView #this is bound to the QCController

...
def AppController

txt = "I did it"  
@myQCView.setValue(txt, forKeyPath:"patch.text.value")  

end
```

I am getting an error:

```
NSUnknownKeyException: [<NSNull 0x7fff7115e000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value. (RuntimeError)
```

I'm stumped. I have tried searching the MacRuby forums but I have had no luck.

thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the exception message:

> ```
> NSUnknownKeyException: [<NSNull 0x7fff7115e000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value. (RuntimeError)
> ```

Why would you be trying to set the key `value` of an NSNull object?

Let's look at the code. What *are* you trying to set the key `value` of?

> ```
> @myQCView.setValue(txt, forKeyPath:"patch.text.value")
> ```

I see: Your QCView's `patch.text`.

So, your QCView's `patch.text` is an NSNull object.

> ```
> attr_accessor :myQCView #this is bound to the QCController
> ```

That's not an accurate name for the variable, then. I suggest “`myQCPatchController`”, or just “`patchController`”.

So it now looks like you're trying to set the value of the `text` port of the root patch. Perhaps the root patch does not actually have a port named `text`?

You may want to ask about this problem on [the Quartz Composer mailing list](http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/quartzcomposer-dev).

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response. I had some help from the macruby dev forum and I had the wrong object bound. I had bound the QCController when I needed to bind the QCView (hence the variable name). My other issue was the @. The code that worked was myQCView.setValue(txt, forKeyPath:"patch.text.value".